# Display a column with an indicator/flag when conditions are met between different columns in pandas dataframe (no-merge)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, transform

Good day all of you. I have a dataframe with region, customer and some deliveries, plus their price. There is this column used as type of purchase and the first and last purchase are marked as 'first' and 'last' and sometimes we have in-between deliveries marked as "delivery". I need to **flag** the *customers and region* that have the *same first and last delivery price*, as a column in the desired output. The whole data must be shown.

I've already solved the problem using merge but I **would like to know if there's a way to do it without using merge** since it doesn't seem that efficient.
Thanks for your time.

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd  
data = [['NY', 'A','FIRST', 25], ['NY', 'A','DELIVERY', 20], ['NY', 'A','DELIVERY', 30], ['NY', 'A','LAST', 25],
       ['NY', 'B','FIRST', 15], ['NY', 'B','DELIVERY', 10], ['NY', 'B','LAST', 20],
       ['FL', 'A','FIRST', 15], ['FL', 'A','DELIVERY', 10], ['FL', 'A','DELIVERY', 12], ['FL', 'A','DELIVERY', 25], ['FL', 'A','LAST', 15],
       ['FL', 'C','FIRST', 15], ['FL', 'C','LAST', 10],
       ['FL', 'D','FIRST', 10], ['FL', 'D','DELIVERY', 20], ['FL', 'D','LAST', 30],
       ['FL', 'E','FIRST', 20], ['FL', 'E','LAST', 20]
       ] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['region', 'customer', 'purchaseType', 'price']) 
  
# print dataframe. 
print(df)

   region customer purchaseType  price
0      NY        A        FIRST     25
1      NY        A     DELIVERY     20
2      NY        A     DELIVERY     30
3      NY        A         LAST     25
4      NY        B        FIRST     15
5      NY        B     DELIVERY     10
6      NY        B         LAST     20
7      FL        A        FIRST     15
8      FL        A     DELIVERY     10
9      FL        A     DELIVERY     12
10     FL        A     DELIVERY     25
11     FL        A         LAST     15
12     FL        C        FIRST     15
13     FL        C         LAST     10
14     FL        D        FIRST     10
15     FL        D     DELIVERY     20
16     FL        D         LAST     30
17     FL        E        FIRST     20
18     FL        E         LAST     20
```

**Expected output:**

```
   region customer purchaseType  price  firstLastEqual
0      NY        A        FIRST     25            True
1      NY        A     DELIVERY     20            True
2      NY        A     DELIVERY     30            True
3      NY        A         LAST     25            True
4      NY        B        FIRST     15           False
5      NY        B     DELIVERY     10           False
6      NY        B         LAST     20           False
7      FL        A        FIRST     15            True
8      FL        A     DELIVERY     10            True
9      FL        A     DELIVERY     12            True
10     FL        A     DELIVERY     25            True
11     FL        A         LAST     15            True
12     FL        C        FIRST     15           False
13     FL        C         LAST     10           False
14     FL        D        FIRST     10           False
15     FL        D     DELIVERY     20           False
16     FL        D         LAST     30           False
17     FL        E        FIRST     20            True
18     FL        E         LAST     20            True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer using 'merge':

```
df_first = df[df['purchaseType'] == 'FIRST']
df_last = df[df['purchaseType'] == 'LAST']
df_compare = df_first.merge(df_last, how='inner', left_on=['region','customer'], right_on=['region','customer'])
df_compare = df_compare[df_compare['price_x'] == df_compare['price_y']]
df_compare['firstLastEqual'] = True
df = df.merge(df_compare, how='left', left_on=['region','customer'], right_on=['region','customer'])
df['firstLastEqual'] = df['firstLastEqual'].fillna(False)
df = df.drop(['purchaseType_x', 'price_x', 'purchaseType_y', 'price_y'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Would like to know if possible without merging.